# How to list/view stored procedure in PhpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I want to list or view created stored procedure in PhpMyAdmin. I have created 1 stored procedure and execute that also but how can i view or modify particular stored procedure is it  possible or not  and please explain its good practise to create stored procedure using PhpMyAdmin or what are the other ways(any other tool) to program with stored procedures , i am new to MySql and PhpMyAdmin .

Please Help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at the information_schema. In your case to the routines table.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/routines-table.html

If you want to list all stored procedures you can use this query

```
select * 
from information_schema.routines
where routine_type = 'procedure'
```

In order to limit the result to a specific database:

```
select * 
from information_schema.routines
where routine_type = 'procedure' and routine_schema = 'your_db'
```

You can find the content of your stored procedures within the routine_definition field.

Moreover take a look at:

```
show create procedure stored_procedure_name
```

you'll find stored procedure content within 'Create Procedure' field.

Comment: In my case the `routine_definition` field is always null. The query `show create procedure` also only returns null in  the `Create Procedure` field. Lastly, in the Routines tab of phpMyAdmin, I can't click any of the 'Execute' or 'Edit' buttons.